# R plot_ly categorical by continuous interaction scatterplot regression lines with colors and symbols

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, lm, interaction

I need to build a scatterplot with two regression lines for two levels of a categorical factor (in my case, gender). The scatterplot should have all the observations, but the linear models for each level need to be plotted separately. In other words, a scatterplot of the following model:

continuousA = intercept + continuousB + categorical + continuousB*categorical.

Plotly does not register the colors specified by add_markers(), unless the add_lines() and add_ribbons() are removed. If this cannot be done with Plotly (a bug?) then can it be done with ggplot (and perhaps GGally)?

Also, I would love to see if this can be done with shorter, tidier, or prettier code, or with a function. It would be even better to do all three iris$Species at once.

```
library(plotly)
library(broom)
plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='versicolor'), ],
            y = ~fitted(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='versicolor'), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
            x = ~Petal.Length,
            line = list(color = "red"),
            name = "Versicolor") %>%
  # Plot the 95% CI of slope ribbon
  add_ribbons(data = augment(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='versicolor'), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
              y = ~Petal.Width,
              x = ~Petal.Length,
              ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
              ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
              line = list(color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)'), #get rid of the border line
              fillcolor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)', #red with alpha transparency
              name = "Versicolor (Standard Error)",
              showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_lines(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='virginica'), ],
            y = ~fitted(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='virginica'), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
            x = ~Petal.Length,
            line = list(color = "green", dash = "dash"),
            name = "Viginica") %>%
  add_ribbons(data = augment(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='virginica'), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
              y = ~Petal.Width,
              x = ~Petal.Length,
              ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
              ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
              line = list(color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)'), #get rid of the border line
              fillcolor = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)', #green with alpha transparency
              name = "Virginica (Standard Error)",
              showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_markers(data = iris[which(iris$Species=='versicolor' | iris$Species=='virginica'), ], 
              x = ~Petal.Length, 
              y = ~Petal.Width,
              symbol = ~Species,
              color = ~Species, colors = c("versicolor" = "red", "virginica" = "green")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Petal Length"), yaxis = list(title = "Petal Width"))
```

[Interaction Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V2ne.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Plotly does not register the colors specified by add_markers(), unless
>   the add_lines() and add_ribbons() are removed. If this cannot be done
>   with Plotly (a bug?) then can it be done with ggplot (and perhaps
>   GGally)?

You could add the markers for your different categories individually, i.e. call `add_markers` repeatedly.

> Also, I would love to see if this can be done with shorter, tidier, or
>   prettier code, or with a function. It would be even better to do all
>   three iris$Species at once.

You could loop over all three species, therefore you would need to write the code only once.

```
library(plotly)
library(broom)

species <-  unique(iris$Species)
colors <- c('(255, 0, 0', '(0, 255, 0', '(0, 0, 255')

p <- plot_ly()

for (i in 1:length(species)) {
  p <- add_lines(p, data = iris[which(iris$Species==species[[i]]), ],
            y = fitted(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species==species[[i]]), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
            x = ~Petal.Length,
            line = list(color = paste('rgb', colors[[i]], ')')),
            name = species[[i]])
    p <- add_ribbons(p, data = augment(lm(data = iris[which(iris$Species==species[[i]]), ], Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length)),
                y = ~Petal.Width,
                x = ~Petal.Length,
                ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
                ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
                line = list(color = paste('rgba', colors[[i]], ', 0.05)')), 
                fillcolor = paste('rgba', colors[[i]], ', 0.1)'),
                showlegend = FALSE)
    p <- add_markers(p, data = iris[which(iris$Species==species[[i]]), ], 
              x = ~Petal.Length, 
              y = ~Petal.Width,
              symbol = ~Species,
              marker=list(color=paste('rgb', colors[[i]])))
}
p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(title = "Petal Length"), yaxis = list(title = "Petal Width"))

p
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maximillian Peters provided an excellent answer to this question. Here is a function I made from his answer.

```
plotly_interaction <- function(data, x, y, category, colors = col2rgb(viridis(nlevels(as.factor(data[[category]])))), ...) {
  # Create Plotly scatter plot of x vs y, with separate lines for each level of the categorical variable. 
  # In other words, create an interaction scatter plot.
  # The "colors" must be supplied in a RGB triplet, as produced by col2rgb().

  require(plotly)
  require(viridis)
  require(broom)

  groups <- unique(data[[category]])

  p <- plot_ly(...)

  for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
    groupData = data[which(data[[category]]==groups[[i]]), ]
    p <- add_lines(p, data = groupData,
                   y = fitted(lm(data = groupData, groupData[[y]] ~ groupData[[x]])),
                   x = groupData[[x]],
                   line = list(color = paste('rgb', '(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ')')),
                   name = groups[[i]],
                   showlegend = FALSE)
    p <- add_ribbons(p, data = augment(lm(data = groupData, groupData[[y]] ~ groupData[[x]])),
                     y = groupData[[y]],
                     x = groupData[[x]],
                     ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
                     ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
                     line = list(color = paste('rgba','(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ', 0.05)')), 
                     fillcolor = paste('rgba', '(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ', 0.1)'),
                     showlegend = FALSE)
    p <- add_markers(p, data = groupData, 
                     x = groupData[[x]], 
                     y = groupData[[y]],
                     symbol = groupData[[category]],
                     marker = list(color=paste('rgb','(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "))))
  }
  p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(title = x), yaxis = list(title = y))
  return(p)
}
```